# Avoid initializing the same storyboard again

Tags: ios, swift

`configureViewController()` method is called every time each ViewControllers `viewWillAppear()` methods gets called; therefore, I am wondering how to avoid multiple places initializing the same `viewcontroller` of the same `storyboard`.

What would be the best approach in this scenario?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
private func loginVC() -> UIViewController {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
}
  
private func homeVC() -> UIViewController {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
}
  
public func configureViewController() {
  if isLoginRequired() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [loginVC()]
    keyWindow?.rootViewController = navigationController
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I get what you mean correctly.

I would suggest to create a property to store the `viewController`, return it if it already existed, or create one when it's not.

For example:

```
var nav: UINavigationController?

public func configureViewController() {
  if isLoginRequired() {
    if let nav = self.nav {
        keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() 
as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.viewControllers = [loginVC()]
        nav = navigationController
        keyWindow?.rootViewController = navigationController
      }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If we want to avoid initializing UIStoryboard again and again, we can just store the UIStoryboard using the same idea.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var keyWindow: UIWindow?
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

private func loginVC() -> UIViewController {
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
}

private func homeVC() -> UIViewController {
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
}

public func configureViewController() {
    if isLoginRequired() {
        let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        // replace the viewControllers in navigationControllers with a whole new stack
        // initialize a new loginVC and put it in the stack
        navigationController.viewControllers = [loginVC()]
        // you can print and check the memory address of the viewController in the navigationController
        print(navigationController.viewControllers) 
        keyWindow?.rootViewController = navigationController
        keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

> therefore, I am wondering how to avoid multiple places initializing the same viewcontroller of the same storyboard.

I am a bit confused about "to avoid initializing the same viewController of the same storyboard", but if you mean "Ensuring that we create a new loginVC instead of using the old one / existing one because we want user to go back to the entry point and login", then you can see from the print statement that the `loginVC()` is a brand new one.

**Additional:**
The above answer is based on iOS version less than 13.0. In iOS13.0+, the handling of UIWindow is recommended to move to SceneDelegate.

Comment: In my code, I have been calling the same thing three times :  `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "xxx")`

Comment: But you are initializing different viewController? or do you mean you don't want to initialize UIStoryboard for multiple time?

Comment: I do not want to initialize the storyboard, again and again.

Comment: By the way, in the following line `keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav`, nothing happens, because `nav` holds all the viewcontroller stack

Comment: oh so you want a new stack of navgiationController every time when isLoginRequired == true. Then maybe we should clear the stack in the current navigationController, init some new viewController and add them in the stack again.

Comment: But when we want to init the new viewController, we will need that storyboard.instantiateViewController()

Comment: Could you please update your answer based on your feedback?

Comment: If the question is not to initialize the UIStoryboard again and again, create a property to store that UIStoryboard. (when you are sure you gonna use it again)

Comment: Based on your suggestion, could you please update your answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Please check if that can help.